# How to avoid one Spark Streaming window blocking another window with both running some native Python code

Tags: python, apache-spark, scikit-learn, spark-streaming

I'm running Spark Streaming with two different windows (on window for training a model with SKLearn and the other for predicting values based on that model) and I'm wondering how I can avoid one window (the "slow" training window) to train a model, without "blocking" the "fast" prediction window.
My simplified code looks as follows:

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local[4]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

stream = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 7000)


import Custom_ModelContainer

### Window 1 ###
### predict data based on model computed in window 2 ###

def predict(time, rdd):
    try:
       # ... rdd conversion to df, feature extraction etc...

       # regular python code 
       X = np.array(df.map(lambda lp: lp.features.toArray()).collect())
       pred = Custom_ModelContainer.getmodel().predict(X)

       # send prediction to GUI

    except Exception, e: print e

predictionStream = stream.window(60,60)
predictionStream.foreachRDD(predict)


### Window 2 ###
### fit new model ###

def trainModel(time, rdd):
try:
    # ... rdd conversion to df, feature extraction etc...

    X = np.array(df.map(lambda lp: lp.features.toArray()).collect())
    y = np.array(df.map(lambda lp: lp.label).collect())

    # train test split etc...

    model = SVR().fit(X_train, y_train)
    Custom_ModelContainer.setModel(model)

except Exception, e: print e

modelTrainingStream = stream.window(600,600)
modelTrainingStream.foreachRDD(trainModel)
```

(Note: The Custom_ModelContainer is a class I wrote to save and retrieve the trained model)

My setup generally works fine, with the exception that every time a new model is trained in the second window (which takes about a minute), the first windows does not compute predictions until model training is finished. Actually, I guess that this makes sense, since model fitting and predictions are both computed on the master node (in a non-distributed setting - due to SKLearn).

So my question is the following: Would it be possible to train the model on a single worker node (instead of the master node)? If so, how could I achieve the latter and would that actually resolve my issue?

If not, any other suggestion on how I could make such a setup work without delaying computations in window 1?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I guess the more general question would be:
How can I run two different task on two different workers in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is only a set of ideas. None of these has been tested in practice.

---

A couple of things you can try:

1. Don't `collect` to `predict`. `scikit-learn` models are typically serializable so prediction process can be easily handled on the cluster:

   ```
   def predict(time, rdd):
       ... 

       model = Custom_ModelContainer.getmodel()
       pred = (df.rdd.map(lambda lp: lp.features.toArray())
           .mapPartitions(lambda iter: model.predict(np.array(list(iter)))))
       ...
   ```

   It should not only parallelize predictions but also, if raw data is not passed to GUI, reduce amount of data that has to be collected.
2. Try to `collect` and send data asynchronously. PySpark doesn't provide `collectAsync` method but you can try to achieve something similar with [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures):

   ```
   from pyspark.rdd import RDD
   from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

   executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)

   def submit_to_gui(*args): ...

   def submit_if_success(f):
       if not f.exception():
           executor.submit(submit_to_gui, f.result())
   ```

   continue from 1.

   ```
   def predict(time, rdd):
       ...
       f = executor.submit(RDD.collect, pred)
       f.add_done_callback(submit_if_success)
       ...
   ```
3. If you really want to use local `scikit-learn` model try to `collect` and `fit` using futures as above. You can also try to collect only once, especially if data is not cached:

   ```
   def collect_and_train(df):
       y, X = zip(*((p.label, p.features.toArray()) for p in df.collect()))
       ...
       return SVR().fit(X_train, y_train)

   def set_if_success(f):
       if not f.exception():
           Custom_ModelContainer.setModel(f.result())  

   def trainModel(time, rdd): 
      ...
       f = excutor.submit(collect_and_train, df)
       f.add_done_callback(set_if_success) 
      ...
   ```
4. Move training process to the cluster either using already existing solutions like [`spark-sklearn`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn) or custom approach:

   - naive solution - prepare your data, `coalesce(1)` and train a single model using `mapPartitions`.
   - distributed solution - create and validate a separate model per partition using `mapPartitions`, collect models and use as an ensemble for example by taking an average or median prediction.
5. Throw away `scikit-learn` and use a model which can be trained and maintained in a distributed, streaming environment (for example [`StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/27c910f7f29087d1ac216d4933d641d6515fd6ad/python/pyspark/mllib/regression.py#L735)).

   Your current approach makes Spark obsolete. If you can train model locally there is a good chance that you can perform all other tasks much faster on the local machine. Otherwise your program will simply fail on `collect`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the property: "spark.streaming.concurrentJobs" which defaults to 1. Increasing this should allow you to run multiple foreachRDD functions in parallel.

[In JobScheduler.scala:](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.0/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/JobScheduler.scala#L47)

```
private val numConcurrentJobs = ssc.conf.getInt("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", 1)
```

Just a reminder to also be aware of thread safety on your custom model container if you're going to be mutating and reading in parallel. :)